L9110H output signals confusion
I directly attached a latch selenoid and driving it by using L9110H. IC is driving by ESP32 digital pins.
But, I am facing with a confusion with L9110H output signals. Over the osiloscope I am observing non-stable signals from L9110H output pins. Please find the waveform when I power up circuit without sending any signal to input pins of L9110H;

Power down:

Circuit schema:

Datasheet L9110H:
https://www.electronicwings.com/components/l9110h-h-bridge-motor-driver/1/datasheet
Is it a normal behavior of L9110H? Thank you for your suggestions.

Orkun Gedik - Hi, Please edit the question and (a) add the schematic diagram; (b) link the datasheet of the IC you are asking about, otherwise every reader has to search for it; (c) have you tried disconnecting that IC from the ESP32 completely (adding any pull-up/down resistors, as required) so that you can remove the ESP32 from the situation completely? If so, explain what happened and your analysis of the result; (d) Explain any other troubleshooting you have done and the results; (e) Don't include a signature here so please delete that when you edit the question. TY
